# Creating a Dataset for a Keras Model with a generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a dataset for audio recognition with a simple Keras sequential model.

This is the function I am using to create the model:

```
def dnn_model(input_shape, output_shape):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.Input(input_shape))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dense(output_shape, activation = "softmax"))
    model.compile(  optimizer='adam',
                    loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), 
                    metrics=['acc'])

    model.summary()
    
    return model
```

I got `wav` files with `TextGrid` and `label` data to train the model and here my problem starts because I think I should use the `wav` files and `TextGrid` files to generate my training data.

These are the functions I am trying to train the model.

```
def generator(x_dirs, y_dirs, hmm, sampling_rate, parameters):
    window_size_samples = tools.sec_to_samples(parameters['window_size'],sampling_rate)
    hop_size_samples = tools.sec_to_samples(parameters['hop_size'],sampling_rate)

    for i in range(len(x_dirs)):
        features  = fe.compute_features_with_context(x_dirs[i],**parameters)
        praat = tools.praat_file_to_target( y_dirs[i],
                                            sampling_rate,
                                            window_size_samples,
                                            hop_size_samples,
                                            hmm)
        yield features,praat

def train_model(model, model_dir, x_dirs, y_dirs, hmm, sampling_rate, parameters, steps_per_epoch=10,
                epochs=10):

    callbacks = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(model_dir,save_best_only=True)
    model.fit((generator(x_dirs, y_dirs, hmm, sampling_rate, parameters)),
                            epochs=epochs,
                            batch_size=steps_per_epoch,callbacks=[callbacks])
    return model
```

Inside the `generator` method the arguments `x_dirs` and `y_dirs` are lists of `audiodata` and `TextGrid` data.

My features I get from the `compute_features_with_context` are numpy array with the first dimension are the number of frames. The second dimension are MFCC-D-DD features which creates 39 features per frame. The last Dimension is the context which adds the the previous 6 features and the next 6 features. So array is a set of 13 features. The full dimensions are (frames*39*13). I hope that makes sense.

These are the errors I get after the first epoch starts.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[157,106] labels_size=[92,106]
     [[node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (defined at /recognizer/dnn_recognizer.py:34) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_584]

Function call stack:
train_function

2020-06-22 20:24:34.951964: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
     [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

### If anything is unclear please ask and thanks for your help!

Edit:
The first Issue was resolved by simply sorting the list I am inputting. I didnt think that the `listdir` method wouldnt keep the order in which they are placed inside the folder.

Now I got a new Error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [109] vs. [108]
     [[node Equal (defined at /recognizer/dnn_recognizer.py:34) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_584]
```

Comment: Hi there! It looks like in your generator, 157 samples are returned, but only 92 labels. Cross entropy requires that the two have the same size/number of items. Is there anything in your generator that could explain why more samples are returned than labels? What does the data/label source look like?

Comment: the ```x_dirs``` and ```y_dirs``` list contain a total of 8623 strings to a ```wav``` file and ```TextGrid``` file, but I dont really understand why I have to use the ```TextGrid``` files. Edit: I think I may found the Error. I think the label is for a totally diffrent soundfile.

Comment: Ok, this new error is something similar. Somehow, your generator gets 109 items from your source, but only 108 labels. Check the label source? Is an item not labeled?

Comment: Thanks I found a computing issue. That now finally partially works. Now I dont know how to setup my Generator correctly but thats a different issue. I guess I have to ask again.